# Stored procedure with temporary tables, Entity Framework updating the stored procedure not working - SET FMTONLY OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx

I have a stored procedure which has multiple temporary tables, when I tried importing it in Entity Framework it didn't create the complex type and I get this error:

> The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns

When I googled, I found adding this piece of code `SET FMTONLY OFF` in the stored procedure will create the complex type in my EDMX. I was able to do it.

Everything works well in Entity Framework now after adding `SET FMTONLY OFF`.

Now my question is, is there a security threat by adding this piece of code to my stored procedure which contains multiple temp tables ?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting to be a security threat here? `SET FMTONLY`? That (deprecated) functionality has no security concerns, no. If you don't understand what it does, check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: There is no *security* threat, but you should still be aware of what happens when you do this -- with `SET FMTONLY OFF`, code actually gets executed instead of merely parsed. This allows the whole thing to succeed despite using temp tables, but it also means actual code is running. That code should then not do bad things when called with default parameters from the designer.

Comment: Should I not use temp tables in my stored procedure? What is the best way to handle my scenario without using the SET FMTONLY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to just SET FMTONLY OFF, as that could have unintended consequences, but you could return an empty result set of the right shape, then turn FMTONLY OFF and RETURN at the beginning of your stored procedure.

eg

```
if 1=0  --this will only run in FMTONLY is ON
begin
  select cast(1 as decimal(12,0) a, cast('x' as nvarchar(20)) b -- . . .
  set fmtonly off
  return;
end
```

Since FMTONLY ignores control flow statements it will run the code in the begin/end.  The client will get an empty resultset, then the procedure exists.  You have to turn off FMTONLY or else the `return` will not be executed, and you will get an error with your temp tables later.

When this stored procedure is run without FMTONLY the `if 1=0` will be evaluated, and that block skipped.

However switching out the stored procedure for one without temp tables when you update the EF model is a valid alternative.

Comment: I didnt understand, do I add this to the top of the SP, execute it, add the SP to entity framework and remove these lines? do I have to write whole structure of my return properties to this begin and end ?